# NodeJS Proxy Server : How to send browser's http request to the internet and write respose back?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, proxy

A Simple proxy server

The below NodeJS TCP server coded for Live proxy functioning at port 8080. Mozilla Firefox configurd at port 8080 sending http headers to this NodeJS application. Everything works fine. I can see the headers in commmand line. But I need to send these headers to the internet dynamically and get respose back. After receiving the response I need to write it in the Server socket to display it on the browser.(Usual browsing)

I comment it on the code. kindly go through the code and give me a solution.

```
const net = require('net')
const PORT = 8080

var clients = []

let date_ob = new Date()
let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2)
let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
let year = date_ob.getFullYear()
let hours = date_ob.getHours()
let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes()
let seconds = date_ob.getSeconds()

const server = net.createServer((socket)=>{

    let sock_name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort
    clients.push(socket)
    
    socket.on('data', (data)=> {
        console.log(year + "-" + month + "-" + date + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds)  
        console.log(sock_name)
/*This "data" should send to internet dynamically like java socket applications and get back the respose*/          
console.log(""+data)        
    })
    
    socket.on('end', ()=>{
      clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1)
      console.log(sock_name +" left\n")
   })
   
   socket.on('error',(error)=>{
     console.log(error) 
   })       
    
}).listen(PORT)

server.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error)  
})

console.log("Server running at port 8080\n")
```

1. The received data from the browser should send to internet.
2. write the respose back to server socket

```
socket.on('data', (data)=> {    
/*This "data" should send to internet dynamically like java socket applications and get back the respose */         
console.log(""+data)        
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a proxy server, you must have not only a server (to receive data), but also a **client** (to send data). Of course, to send data to any other server, you need to know the PORT and HOST of the server (in the code below - remoteHost and remotePort).

Here is an example:

```
const net = require('node:net');

class ProxyClient {
  constructor(config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  async setup() {
    const { proxyClient } = this.config;
    if (!proxyClient) {
      return;
    }

    const { localPort, remoteHost, remotePort } = proxyClient;
    const serviceSocket = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      const socket = new net.Socket();
      socket.connect(remotePort, remoteHost, () => resolve(socket));
    });

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      const server = net.createServer((proxyServerSocket) => {
        proxyServerSocket.on('data', (message) => {
          serviceSocket.write(message);
        });
        serviceSocket.on('data', (message) => {
          proxyServerSocket.write(message);
        });
        proxyServerSocket.on('error', (error) => {
          console.log('Proxy server error', error);
        });
      });
      server.listen(localPort, '0.0.0.0', () => resolve());
    });
  }
}

const proxy = new ProxyClient({
  localPort: 8080,
  remoteHost: '192.192.192.192',
  remotePort: 4321,
});

proxy.setup()
  .then(()=> console.log('proxy server started'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err);
```